# Click on an element without resource-id and content-desc using appium

Tags: python, appium

Using Appium, I want to click on a button on a website. But the button has no resource-id, content-desc. 
So,is there any method by which we can click on the button.
I am using python language for writing scripts to run.[this image has the description of various attributes of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKzeU.png)

Comment: Please add some more info on the button so that we can help you

Comment: Please show the snapshot of the inspector for the button

Comment: @john I have added the snapshot of the inspector for the button.

Comment: Since this is a website, are you able to access the web element through selenium? The image is showing a native app instead of a web element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect webelement of nativeapp screen which is based on web

You need to hit below URL in your desktop machine which has code

```
chrome://inspect#devices
```

Make user your devices is connected using **adb devices** and the same screen must be open mobile screen.

Detail Article :

https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/inspect-elements-of-mobile-web-application/

Comment: I am able to inspect elements. The inspector is not showing any resource-id, Content-desc, name of the element. The button neither has id nor name. Thus, through the appium script how to locate that button.

Comment: Resource-id etc is shown if it is a native app or hybrid app ... if it is web based hybrid app and web app you need to use selenium locator like id etc

Comment: Not able to find any id or unique attribute using the locators as well